# Socket.io client connects to multiple servers at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io

I'm using nodejs and socket.io and I'm curious. What if 1 client connects to multiple
servers like so:

```
socket = io.connect('http://server1') //600k sockets already connected
socket2 = io.connect('http://server2') // 100k sockets already connected
socket3 = io.connect('http://server3') // 1 million sockets already connected
socket4 = io.connect('http://server4') // 999k sockets already connected
```

Will there be any performance issues for the server or client? Will the client be able to maintain all the connections with already so many connected?

I like absurd scenarios as it helps me to better understand whats going on.

Comment: Four connections is no burden at all for the client.  Whether or not the servers can handle as many connections as you're hypothesizing is a whole different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will there be any performance issues for the server or client?

For every connection there is a slight overhead for heartbeats, handshakes and things like that but those shouldn't be measurable. Wether you send the data over one connection or two shouldn't matter, just the amount of data matters.

> Will the client be able to maintain all the connections with already so many connected?

Sure, the only limits are memory and bandwith, which are both quite high these days.

Comment: upvoted! I am trying to connect to multiple crypto exchanges to fetch tickers orderbooks etc, given each exchange almost sends this data for 500+ pairs, wont that be a performance bottleneck, how do I use say cluster with this? i have seen cluster socketio server examples left and right but havent found client ones

Comment: @priateApp you realize that "a cluster" only makes sense if you got "a cluster" ?

Comment: Sorry, my question is something like this, if I have 8 cores on my machine and I want to connect to 8 different urls from a socketio client on node or python, can I do so, i am a newbie to socketio and have grasped the simple examples so far but i havent found an answer to this yet

Comment: @pirateApp but you got just one network connection right? That will be the bottleneck